# Cannot generate auto decoder for MongoDB.Bson.BsonObjectId

Tags: mongodb, f#

I'm trying to create an user and add the info into MongoDB.

The type looks like this.

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type User =
    { 
    Id: BsonObjectId
    Name: string
    LastName: string
    Role: string
    Email: string
    Password: string 
  }
```

and signup function,

```
let signup : HttpHandler =
   fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
       task {
            
            let! payload = ctx.BindJsonAsync<User>()
            let updated = updateUserPassword (payload, BCrypt.HashPassword(payload.Password, 10))
            try
                do! UserCollection.InsertOneAsync updated
                let maybe = UserCollection.Find(fun user -> user.Email = payload.Email).ToEnumerable() |> Seq.tryHead
                match maybe with
                | Some doc -> return! Successful.OK (userToDTO (doc)) next ctx
                | None -> return! RequestErrors.BAD_REQUEST "Invalid User" next ctx
            with :? Exception -> return! ServerErrors.INTERNAL_ERROR "Something Went Wrong" next ctx
        }
```

But when I try to create the user I get error :
**Cannot generate auto decoder for MongoDB.Bson.BsonObjectId**

If I change the Id to **Id:string**, I can save to the DB so connection works. But using string will not have the effect I want of course.
Where reading this post, but cannot see what the difference really are :(
https://medium.com/@mukund.sharma92/cruding-in-f-with-mongodb-e4699d1ac17e

And the repo I'm playing with is
https://github.com/AngelMunoz/Giraffarig

Thanks in advance

Comment: It fails on the `InsertOneAsync` call, and the document is not inserted?

Comment: After researching this a bit, I've discovered that the error message you're seeing comes from a package called "[Thoth.Json](https://github.com/thoth-org/Thoth.Json/blob/2ac99b7dbcc88d0814cb32f81a1583aba83eca9b/src/Decode.fs)", so it's probably not related to MongoDB at all.

Comment: @brianberns Hi. It actually fails already at  let! payload = ctx.BindJsonAsync<User>().
That is why it works when I change Id: BsonObjectId to Id:string

Will check Thoth.json, were did you find this info? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I found it by searching Github for the string "Cannot generate auto decoder".

Comment: @brianberns maybe this is not related but I cannot seem to get this to work :)
The only place I use Thoth, is when I add a singleton in services. 

    services
        .AddSingleton(typeof<IJsonSerializer>, ThothSerializer())
        |> ignore

Comment: I think the problem is that Thoth doesn't know how to convert a BsonObjectId from JSON into your object model. Are you using Thoth on the server side, or on the client with Fable? This error is occurring on the server, I assume.

Comment: @brianberns Only server side, and no fable. just shooting in through postman.
This GIT is basically what I have done 
https://github.com/AngelMunoz/Giraffarig

Comment: OK, I've reproduced what you're seeing using the Giraffarig template. It seems very odd to me to expect that the client side will send a valid `BsonObjectId` in the `User` object during signup. It might be best to ask Angel Munoz how this is supposed to work, since his code right now is definitely broken.

Comment: @brianberns I'll do that! thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at this a while, I think the solution is to modify the `signup` function so that it works like the `login` function. Specifically:

- Create a type called `SignupPayload` in Types.fs that is similar to the existing `LoginPayload` type. The `SignupPayload` type should contain all of the `User` fields *except* `BsonObjectId`.
- Modify the `signup` function to deserialize the payload.
- Use the deserialized payload to build and save an actual `User` object.

So the final code looks something like this:

```
let! payload = ctx.BindJsonAsync<SignupPayload>()
let user = payload |> SignupPayload.toUser
let updated = updateUserPassword (user, BCrypt.HashPassword(user.Password, 10))
```

Comment: cool. I can see why this should work,. but getting error in SignupPayload.toUser : The type 'SignupPayload does not define the field,contruct or member 'toUser'
I am using CLIMutable in the SignupPayload type.

Comment: You would need to write that function yourself. It simply copies each field from the payload into a new `User` object. Alternatively, you could try to insert the payload object directly into the MongDB collection, assuming the driver will automatically supply an object ID. I can try this myself later on today if you want.

Comment: haha of course :) sorry im such a noob at this. will try to do the function. Awesome help so far! thank you so much!!

Comment: Got it working with a Thoth.json decoder! thanks for the suggestions.